# QIWI API - при оплате выставленного счёта ошибка http.missing.request.parameter

Tags: php, qiwi

Пытаюсь оплатить выставленный счёт через API интерфейс киви, но мне в ответе приходит ошибка:

> [serviceName] => checkout-api
>
> [errorCode] => http.missing.request.parameter
>
> ```
> [description] => Missing request parameter(s)
>
> [userMessage] => Missing request parameter(s)
>
> [dateTime] => 1542030242.591
> ```

Почитал про ошибку, якобы переданы не все параметры.

Вот какие параметры требует киви:

> ```
> Параметры
> Параметры передаются в теле запроса в формате JSON. Все параметры обязательны.
> ```
>
> invoice_uid,currency

Вот что и как я передаю

```
// Оплатить счёт
function payBill(){
$data = array("invoice_uid" => "номер_счёта", "currency" => "643");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);  

$curl   = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://edge.qiwi.com/checkout/invoice/pay/wallet');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ***',
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
)); 

$result = curl_exec($curl);

if( curl_error($curl) ){
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
    die;
}

curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
die;
}
```

В итоге мне выбивает ту ошибку.

В чем косяк?

Документация киви:
https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/?http#paywallet_invoice

Через постман отправляю запрос этот-же и он успешно обрабатывается. 
и из постмана беру код пхп который он генерирует, пытаюсь отправить его - не отправляет. Волшебство

Comment: Не вижу у вас в коде параметры description и userMessage, а про них в тексте ошибки написано

Comment: @gil9red это описание ошибки для разработчиков насколько я понял, попробовал добавить в запрос эти параметры - ничего не изменилось

Comment: Действительно, в документации нет упоминания об этих полях, лучше спросите техподдержку qiwi об этой ошибке

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю: в коде, который вы запускаете, invoice_uid указан корректно, заголовок Authorization тоже?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин да, верно

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением заголовка User-Agent

ответ от тех.поддержки qiwi:

> У вас в запросе отсутствует обязательный (по умолчанию, он подставляется во всех запросах) заголовок User-Agent. Добавьте его в запрос.

Comment: Useragent в API. Бред. Кто до такого додумался.